# Can I join a conference call in Skype?

Tags: skype

Running Ubuntu 12.04, with the latest Skype.  How can I join a conference call in Skype?  Skype doesn't seem to allow joining conference calls, only creating new ones. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is the same as accepting any other call in Skype. When someone calls you with Skype, just click Answer or Answer with Video. If the call is a conference call, than you will be able to see and hear all of the participants once you have joined.